# ES Lint Installation errors on Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint

I am trying to install ES Lint on Ubuntu and getting a bundle of errors and i am not able to figure out what the errors are and how to fix them.
The command that i used to install ESlint:

```
npm init @eslint/config
```

I am running:

- Ubuntu 20.08
- Node 18.13.0
- npm 8.19.3

Here are the list of errors that i got:

```
Error: A package.json file is necessary to initialize ESLint. Run `npm init` to create a package.json file and try again.
    at promptUser (file:///home/syedfaheem/.npm/_npx/7ef27be80482e586/node_modules/@eslint/create-config/lib/init/config-initializer.js:370:15)
    at initializeConfig (file:///home/syedfaheem/.npm/_npx/7ef27be80482e586/node_modules/@eslint/create-config/lib/init/config-initializer.js:586:12)
    at file:///home/syedfaheem/.npm/_npx/7ef27be80482e586/node_modules/@eslint/create-config/bin/create-config.js:10:1
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)

Node.js v18.13.0
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/syedfaheem
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c -- create-config

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/syedfaheem/.npm/_logs/2023-02-27T05_48_54_008Z-debug-0.log
```

I didn't understand the errors, so I didn't try much.

Comment: The message is telling you that you don't have a `package.json` where you are trying to run eslint from. You didn't mention what command you were trying to run.

Comment: I ran this command to install Eslint- npm init @eslint/config

Comment: "I didn't try much" is not the way to learn. Debugging your problem is a requirement before posting a question. See https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Answer (score 1):

The relevant error message:

> A package.json file is necessary to initialize ESLint. Run `npm init` to create a package.json file and try again.

You need to first run `npm init` (without arguments) to create a `package.json`:

```
npm init --yes && npm init @eslint/config
```

[@eslint/config docs](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/getting-started):

> Note: `npm init @eslint/config` assumes you have a `package.json` file already. If you don’t, make sure to run `npm init` or `yarn init` beforehand.